# Problema com validação documento HTML

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Quando valido meu documento HTML esta dando o seguinte problema

> Section lacks heading. Consider using h2-h6 elements

Mas eu não preciso disso, é realmente desnecessário para o proposito do meu site (títulos apenas em artigos, estilo blog). Posso ignorar isso ou pode me prejudicar? Sendo forçado a esconder esse título no CSS?

#### Exemplo do meu código

```
 <header>
       <h1></h1> --
       <nav>
       </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
       <section>
          <article>
             <h2></h2> --
          </article>
       </section>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiser conformar com este padrão precisa colocar um cabeçalho, como foi feito.

E é claro que pode ignorar alertas que bem entender. Não vejo problemas se é seu desejo. Não é uma obrigação, não é um erro oficial, é apenas uma recomendação.

Se ainda quiser conformar com o padrão e não ter este alerta considere mudar a `<section>` por uma `<div>`, por exemplo. Uma seção exige um cabeçalho, uma divisão não exige. A decisão é sua de qual é mais adequado.

[Especificação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element).

Comment: Entendo, mt obg pela resposta